# Cannot push a variable to the dataLayer through a Custom HTML tag

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a custom HTML tag with a DOM trigger. Can see the tag firing but no variable is pushed into the data layer.

The custom HTML tag has the following code

`<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; window.dataLayer.push({ 'myVariable' : 'myValue' }); </script>`

This tag has a trigger which is page view - DOM ready

Nothing in the data layer even though I can see the tag firing in debug mode

I attach a screenshot of the tag output in debugger

[Tag Debugger Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51utA.png)

[Tag Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIneF.png)

Comment: How do you check your dataLayer? Add another screenshot.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)